# How to UPDATE with JOIN performance in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, sql-update

I have two tables with some users id

and in second table like to mark all users that are in first table 
so I have query

```
UPDATE tableB AS B 
LEFT JOIN tableA AS A ON lower(B.other_id) = lower(A.user_id) 
SET B.found = 1 WHERE A.user_id IS NOT NULL;
```

But when I have 20k in one table and 10k in other sometimes this query takes more than 20min

I have indexes in both tables on other_id and user_id, those fields are not primary keys

In explain I don't see those indexes are used

Comment: `WHERE user_id IS NOT NULL` in which table does this `user_id` belong?

Comment: LEFT JOIN... IS NOT NULL? Isn't that just JOIN?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your query:

```
UPDATE tableB B LEFT JOIN
       tableA A
       ON lower(B.other_id) = lower(A.user_id) 
    SET B.found = 1
    WHERE A.user_id IS NOT NULL;
```

This query cannot make use of your indexes.  The cases should be the same in both tables, so you'll find that a `join` is much faster without `lower()`:

```
UPDATE tableB B LEFT JOIN
       tableA A
       ON B.other_id = A.user_id
    SET B.found = 1
    WHERE A.user_id IS NOT NULL;
```

If the case of the columns makes a difference and they are not the same, then fix the data using `update`.